# Microsoft Excel - How to select certain data and display it separately

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've created a simple image that will entirely explain what I need to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Could you let us know what you've tried and where the problem is exactly?

Comment: Are you willing to program in VBA?

Comment: The problem is I have no real idea of where to start. Yes I am willing to use VB.

Comment: Are you required to use a checkbox? What if you simply put, say, an `x` in the cell where you want the CAT ID? That would make this easily possible without VBA.

Comment: Should the result be in a text box, or can it also be a (merged) cell? And if it should appear in a text box, must htis be on the sheet or on a form?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Cat IS` is in cell `A1`, program your first checkbox to fill in `C2` to fill in `", "&A1` in `C2` if it is checked and blank otherwise.

Your can now get your result as `=mid(concatenate(C1:C100), 2, 1000)`. If required, write code to put this result in the text box.

*Depending on your feedback, I will further elaborate this sollution.*